# How to downgrade Python version from 3.9 to 3.7?

Tags: python

I'm working on a RaspberryPi.
These are my OS informations:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -m
armv7l

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

My actual Python version is:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python --version
Python 3.9.2
```

I would need to install `Python 3.7` without uninstalling the current version. I simply want to install the 3.7 version and make it enabled. I tried `sudo apt install python3.7` but it didn't work. How to do it?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt install python3.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package python3.7 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3.7' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information on why you need Python3.7 specifically (3.9 should be backwards compatible) and what happened when you tried to `apt install` it?

Comment: What didn't work? It's perfectly possible to have multiple versions of Python installed (and you absolutely do *not* want to uninstall the system-managed version of Python that the OS or OS services may rely on), and use a virtual environment to select which version to use for a given project.

Comment: seems like you are missing some dependency , how about you do `sudo apt --fix-missing update` and then `sudo apt install -f` and maybe after that `sudo apt --fix-broken install`?? does it fix the issue?

Comment: sudo apt --fix-missing update
Hit:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) for multiple python versions management.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

First install the 3.7 python:

`$sudo apt install python3.7`

Then create venv with 3.7 version of python, this way:

`$python3.7 -m venv my-venv`

Sources:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/qt303s/is_there_a_way_to_downgrade_python_on_fedora_35/

[Downgrade Python version in virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71831415/downgrade-python-version-in-virtual-environment)