pip install psycopg2-binary
When I am tryping to use pip install psycopg2-binary in Windows CMD virtual Environment, I get below error:
Collecting psycopg2-binary
  Downloading psycopg2-binary-2.9.10.tar.gz (385 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      running egg_info
      creating C:\Users\Nafees Ahmad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-fbk58flv\psycopg2_binary.egg-info
      writing C:\Users\Nafees Ahmad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-fbk58flv\psycopg2_binary.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Nafees Ahmad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-fbk58flv\psycopg2_binary.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to C:\Users\Nafees Ahmad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-fbk58flv\psycopg2_binary.egg-info\top_level.txt
      writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Nafees Ahmad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-fbk58flv\psycopg2_binary.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

      Error: pg_config executable not found.

      pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
      containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
      option:

          python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

      or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

      If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
      'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.


Collecting psycopg2-binary
  Downloading psycopg2-binary-2.9.10.tar.gz (385 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      running egg_info
      creating C:\Users\Nafees Ahmad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-fbk58flv\psycopg2_binary.egg-info
      writing C:\Users\Nafees Ahmad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-fbk58flv\psycopg2_binary.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Nafees Ahmad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-fbk58flv\psycopg2_binary.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to C:\Users\Nafees Ahmad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-fbk58flv\psycopg2_binary.egg-info\top_level.txt
      writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Nafees Ahmad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-fbk58flv\psycopg2_binary.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

      Error: pg_config executable not found.

      pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
      containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
      option:

          python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

      or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

      If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
      'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.


What is ouyr python version? If it is python 3.13, then downgrade to 3.12

Please [edit] and show us the text output from pip --version

@phd no it is not, only linux and mac

I had Python 3.13 and got the same error when tried to install psycopg2-binary.
I downgrade Python to 3.12 as per FlyingTeller recommendation and it fixed the error.
Please see the answer on how to downgrade Python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75710481/15400268
